# How to highlight text within & out of tags?

Tags: javascript, regex, tags, string-matching, replace

I'm developing WebApp. I've feature to quicksearch for articles.

In two words structure is:

- Page
- Global array (json, 100-150 items) with articles which is fetched by ajax. (with fields: id, title, snippet). Title & Snippet may contain simple style markup tags.

So, when user type query in popup-quicksearch field, app

1. Search in global array
2. If found matches, `push` to temporary search results array (with cache)
3. Highlight matches in temp. results array and show to user

As you can see, original array doesn't modifing.

Currenty i'm using primitive `String.indexOf`, but it cannot match text within formatted via html tags text (example below):

Question is about RegEx patterns. I clearly understand that it's not recommended to use RegEx to manipulate with DOM and expecting results below isn't semantically correct but ***it fits needs***.

For example:
we have something like this:

`<ul><li>Item <i><span style="color:red">Y</span></i></li></ul>`

and we need to highlight query `e`, expecting result: `... It<em>e</em>m ...`, but if use trivial `replace(/e/ig, '<em>$&</em>')` it will replace `e` in `style="color:red"` too.

i.e. what RegEx pattern to do not touch words in tags?

---

Second example: we need to highlight `Item Y`, so expecting result is `<ul><li><em>Item <i><span style="color:red">Y</em></span></i></li></ul>`

Comment: "I clearly understand that it's not recommended to use RegEx" ... no, you obviously don't. Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to search within text contents of a fragment of a DOM tree. One way of achieving this is to use the XML/HTML text contents. This examples makes use of jQuery, but the idea is easily portable to other libs:

HTML:

```
<div id="article_contents">
Blah blah blah, Item 1, Item 2 blah blah <b>Ite</b>m <span>1</span> blah blah
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var source = jQuery('#article_contents').text();
var queryRegexp = new RegExp ( 'Item 1', 'g' );
var results = source.match (queryRegexp);
```

Now `results` will hold all occurences of your search string. Of course to achieve your goal of highlighting results you must go a few steps further (like using RegExp.exec to get the offsets of the matches).

Answer (score -1):

A short hackish solution is to look for markup between every single letter of the search string. If your keyword is "search" it would look like this:

`(s)(<[.^>]*>)*(e)(<[.^>]*>)*(a)(<[.^>]*>)*(r)(<[.^>]*>)*(c)(<[.^>]*>)*(h)`

But in reality you need to do more than that, because:

- scripts
- textareas
- `display:none`, `visibility:hidden`, etc

Comment: as i described above there aren't whose tags in data to search. text with simple style markup tags.

Comment: this regex [doesnt work](http://regexr.com?30i4d) for 1st example (matched text in tag) & [doesnt work](http://regexr.com?30i4a) for 2nd example.

Comment: dummy comment for notify @grigore :)

Comment: I haven't tested at all, it was just how it's supposed to look like; see http://txt2re.com, match `these <tag> are </tag> my <i><b>s</b>earch keywords</i>` and if you're supposed to wrap **my search** in `<span>` tags in that markup (without actually wrapping every single character) you'll end up with a </span> in the middle of some other tag, on a different DOM tree level.